# Is there a jQuery selector that looks for a substring NOT being there?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Currently the following allows me to attach a handler for all id's under the #container div that have "test" in it:

```
$('#container').delegate("input[id*='test']", 'click', function(event) {
    // code
}
```

Is there a way to do the same but to look for all id's that do NOT have test in them?

Thanks!

Comment: Rocket's answer is correct, and the same I would say given that exact problem, however, this seems like there must be a better way to accomplish this. Do you not have control over the html, why not add classes to select by?

Comment: The reason the code is like this is because I've simplified the code to make it easier and more specific for the reader. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to negate your `id*='test'` selector:

```
$('#container').delegate("input:not([id*='test'])", 'click', function(event) {
    //code
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to add another criteria in there like two :nots?

Comment: @Goalie: Sure, just add more selectors.  Like `"input:not([id*='test']):not(.red)"` (this is AND), or `"input:not([id*='test']), input:not(.red)"` (this is OR).